# How can we log Custom Activity data against leads with Marketo REST API?

Tags: marketo

We have created a Custom Activity with Marketo web portal, and we are able to create leads with REST API. So now, how can we log Custom Activity data using Marketo REST API?
Custom Activity structure is as follows:

```js
{
    "id": 100001,
    "name": "TEST_ACTIVITY",
    "apiName": "test_api_c",
    "description": "",
    "primaryAttribute": {
        "name": "event_id",
        "apiName": "event_id",
        "dataType": "string"
    },
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "email",
            "apiName": "email",
            "dataType": "email"
        },
        {
            "name": "event_data",
            "apiName": "event_data",
            "dataType": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push your custom activity records to the [Add Custom Activities](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Activities/addCustomActivityUsingPOST) endpoint, which is available at the `POST /rest/v1/activities/external.json` url.

First, worth to note, that in order to use the endpoint, the API user has to have the “Read-Write Activity” permission.
The endpoint expects a payload with a single `input` key, that can hold up to 300 activity records. For each activity record the **leadId**, **activityDate**, **activityTypeId**, **primaryAttributeValue** and **attributes** fields are required, and in case of the attributes array, the `name` is the normal “name” field, not the “apiName”.

In your case the payload would look something like this:

```js
{  
    "input":[// Note the array of records
        {
            "activityDate":"2018-03-20T22:43:12+02:00",
            "activityTypeId":100001,
            "leadId":<LEAD_ID>,
            "primaryAttributeValue":"<YOUR_EVENT_ID>",
            "attributes":[
                {
                    "name":"email",// This is the `name` field of the attribute, not the `apiName`!
                    "value":"<EMAIL_ADDRESS>"
                },
                {
                    "name":"event_data",// This is the `name` field of the attribute, not the `apiName`!
                    "value":"<EVENT_DATA>"
                }
            ]
        },
        //{
        //  …other activity records…
        //}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do same(post custom activity) without having lead id. Needed for 2 cases - 1. anonymous user activity 2. user just logged in via custom form as my code still doesn't have lead id rather has only email id